# View full HTML comment length in Firefox DevTools

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, inspector

Is there any way to show by default the full length of every HTML comment in the inspector tab? I work on a very large site and we store every included template and config's path in comments, this makes our job faster and easier when we need to find something. 
Clicking every comment one by one is annoying and slow, I usually need to see all in once, cause few pages have more config's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this by adding an HTML comment containing almost 300.000 characters (split over 500 lines), and was able to see the comment in full without having to click on it.

I tested this in Firefox 49, 50 and 51 and all worked fine.

I used the following test page:
http://jsbin.com/ruhaquyela/edit?html,output

I think there was a related change in bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1202458 which landed in Firefox 49, so if you're testing with 48, you might want to update.

Comment: Nice, this will roll out on the 23th of September. I've checked it in the Developer Edition and it worked, thanks :)